# Simplifying multiple combinations of data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need help making data I have in pandas dataframe easier to understand. I have merged three .txt files to one dataframe but now have multiple combinations of the same dates sets of dates, which isn't what I want and am not sure how to simplify this. How my data reads now:

| Product | Date 1 | Data field 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entry 1 | 5/11/2021 | 9592208 | 3/30/2032 |
| Entry 1 | 5/11/2021 | 9592208*PED | 9/30/2032 |
| Entry 1 | 11/11/2021 | 9592208 | 3/30/2032 |
| Entry 1 | 11/11/2021 | 9592208*PED | 9/30/2032 |
| Entry 1 | 5/11/2021 | 9187405 | 6/25/2027 |
| Entry 1 | 5/11/2021 | 10543179 | 12/25/2027 |
| Entry 1 | 5/11/2021 | 8324283 | 3/29/2026 |
| Entry 1 | 5/11/2021 | 8324283*PED | 9/29/2026 |
| Entry 1 | 5/11/2021 | 9187405*PED | 12/25/2027 |
| Entry 1 | 11/11/2021 | 9187405 | 6/25/2027 |
| Entry 1 | 11/11/2021 | 10543179 | 12/25/2027 |
| Entry 1 | 11/11/2021 | 8324283 | 3/29/2026 |
| Entry 1 | 11/11/2021 | 8324283*PED | 9/29/2026 |
| Entry 1 | 11/11/2021 | 9187405*PED | 12/25/2027 |

But all I really care about is producing two lists of the unique dates from each column, that I can track back to entry 1. So what I want to get is something more like this:

| Item | Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Entry 1 | 5/11/2021 | 3/30/2032 |
|  | 11/11/2021 | 9/30/2032 |
|  |  | 6/25/2027 |
|  |  | 12/25/2027 |
|  |  | 3/29/2026 |
|  |  | 9/29/2026 |
|  |  | 12/25/2027 |

When I simply drop the datafield1, I still get all of the combinations of dates, rather than being able to simplify down. Same for when I try to use .drop_duplicates, which makes sense. And I need to do this for several hundred different products. Does this make any sense and can anyone recommend a good way to do this or a better way to think about arranging this? Thanks for any help!

EDIT
Here's some of the code I have for this part, just getting the dataframe setup and trying to sort and get rid of anything extra

```
#merging in the patent expiration dates
prods_ex_pats = pd.merge(prods_ex,dfpat)

# dropping any nonunique exclusivity and patent dates
prods_ex_pats = prods_ex_pats.drop_duplicates(subset=['appl_no','exclusivity_date','patent_no','patent_expire_date_text'],keep='first')

#Sorting by patents and exclusivity dates
prods_ex_pats['exclusivity_date']=pd.to_datetime(prods_ex_pats['exclusivity_date'])
prods_ex_pats['patent_expire_date_text']=pd.to_datetime(prods_ex_pats['patent_expire_date_text'])
prods_ex_pats.sort_values(by=['exclusivity_date','patent_expire_date_text'])
```

Comment: Seems like you want to use pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by item and date1

Comment: Please post code - forget the table, initialize a dataframe for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby

```
>>> df.groupby(['Product','Date 1', 'Date 2']).agg(list)

                                          Data field 1
Product Date 1     Date 2
Entry 1 11/11/2021 12/25/2027  [10543179, 9187405*PED]
                   3/29/2026                 [8324283]
                   3/30/2032                 [9592208]
                   6/25/2027                 [9187405]
                   9/29/2026             [8324283*PED]
                   9/30/2032             [9592208*PED]
        5/11/2021  12/25/2027  [10543179, 9187405*PED]
                   3/29/2026                 [8324283]
                   3/30/2032                 [9592208]
                   6/25/2027                 [9187405]
                   9/29/2026             [8324283*PED]
                   9/30/2032             [9592208*PED]
```